# Download Gitlab's graphql schema

Tags: graphql, gitlab

I'm trying to get hold of gitlab_schema.graphql, i.e. the schema for Gitlab's graphql API. Can't find it anywhere, does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the schema is an artifact in the Gitlab CI pipe (graphql-schema-dump job), for example here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/jobs/1602029144.

Not perfect, but works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apollo CLI for this: `apollo client:download-schema --endpoint=https://gitlab.yourcompany.com/api/graphql schema.graphql` or just omit  filename and it will download to JSON

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like GitLab shares the schema directly, just this [Reference Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/reference/#connection-types) generated from the schema, and the [GraphiQL Explorer / IDE](https://gitlab.com/-/graphql-explorer) (more info about GraphiQL Explorer [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/getting_started.html#graphiql)).

Comment: Yeah, which is really weird.. was hoping to use a rust lib (https://crates.io/crates/graphql_client) to avoid manually hacking the queries, but maybe I'll end up doing just that.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't find any issues about it when searching, but they're pretty good about responding there if you want to [open one](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

Here's alternative, if you are working with [Rust lang](https://rust-lang.org). For [Rust](https://rust-lang.org) developers, you need to install the [crate](https://crates.io) named `graphql_client_cli` via [cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/index.html). Example: `cargo install graphql_client_cli`.

Next, you can run the graphql *client* you just downloaded, to get the schema (either in [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) or [GraphQL](https://graphql.org) format). Example: `graphql-client --authorization 'Bearer <bearer token>' https://<your gitlab url site>/api/graphql`.

See the [GraphQL Client CLI](https://crates.io/crates/graphql_client_cli) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

If you clone the [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab) codebase, you can get the IDL and JSON version of the full graphql schema by running the following rake task within the project:

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:graphql:schema:dump
```